# SQl Insert Into Tables Autoamtically?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table for holding student datat in a school, this DB holds information about who the student is, what sujects they study, who their tutors are, and what modules etc.Tables are as follows:

```
Student(**StudentId**,name,address,dob,contactNum,classId)
classes(**classId**,className,totalStudents)
modules(**moduleId**,name,lecturer)
lecturers(**staffId**,name,moduleId)
registeredClass(moduleId,staffId)
moduleRegistartions(studentId,moduleId)
```

If i was to add data to the lecturers table, how could it automactically / garantee that the inserts would be completed in one action Rather than having to individually insert data into the registeredClass table.

Thanks

Comment: use insert triggers and foreign key constraints.  What db platform are you using?

Comment: MySQL, im not sure of these how do i use them?

Comment: If it can be "automatically inserted" there is likely a normalization issue as this implies some of the (same) import data is duplicated.

Comment: Im sure its using the triggers i need to do it, but just not sure on how to use triggers thats ll

Comment: So you need to read up on how to use triggers, right?

Comment: Why do you have the `moduleId` field in `lecturers` to begin with?

Comment: not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trgInsertLecturers` AFTER INSERT ON `lecturers` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN       

    INSERT INTO registeredClass(moduleId,staffId) values(NEW.moduleId, NEW.staffId);

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```